# Vue.js editar post pelo id

Tags: html5, vue.js

Estou começando com vue.js e estou carregando alguns posts do banco de dados na tela com o `v-for` do vue.js. Tenho duas funcionalidades (editar e excluir) em dois botões distintos embaixo de cada post.

A funcionalidade de excluir já está funcionando corretamente pegando pelo `id` do post a ser deletado.

A funcionalidade de editar já está abrindo um `input` do título do post pra ser editado. Só não estou conseguindo gravar as alterações feitas e quando clico no botão de editar ele abre o `input` em todos os posts.

Então, preciso abrir somente no post desejado (pelo id) e preciso gravar as alterações feitas nesse `input`.

html:

```
<div id="app" class="row mb-50">
    <div v-for="(item, index) in tours" v-bind:key="item.id" id="tours" class="col-md-12 mb-30">
        <div class="tour-list">
            <div class="tour-list-title">
                <p>
                    <input type="text" ref="item.id" :value="item.title" :disabled="!editingTour"
                        :class="{view: !editingTour}" />
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="tour-list-description">
                <p>
                    {{ item.description }}
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="tour-list-options">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <span>
                            <button @click="editingTour = !editingTour" v-if="!editingTour"
                                class="btn border btn-circle tour-list-edit-btn">Editar</button>
                        </span>
                        <span>
                            <button @click="save" v-if="editingTour"
                                class="btn border btn-circle tour-list-edit-btn">Salvar</button>
                        </span>
                        <span>
                            <button @click="editingTour = false" v-if="editingTour"
                                class="btn border btn-circle tour-list-delete-btn">Cancelar</button>
                        </span>
                        <span>
                            <button @click="deleteTour(item.id, index)" v-if="!editingTour"
                                class="btn border btn-circle tour-list-delete-btn">Excluir</buton>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- main row -->
```

vue.js

```
let app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
    editingTour: false,
        tours: null,
        errored: false,
        edited: false,
        deleted: false,
        item: {
            title: null,
            description: null
        }
    },
    created: function () {
        this.searchTour()
    },
    methods: {
        searchTour: function () {
            axios.post('getPosts.php', { "token": param }).then((response) => {
                this.tours = response.data;
            }).catch((error) => {
                this.errored = error;
            });
        },
        editTour: function (id) {
            axios.post('editPosts.php', { "token": token, "tourID": id }).then((response) => {
                this.edited = response.data;
            }).catch((error) => {
                this.errored = error;
            });
        },
        deleteTour: function (id) {
            if (confirm('Deseja realmente apagar este post?')) {
                const index = this.tours.findIndex(item => item.id === id);
                if (~index) {
                    axios.post('deletePosts.php', { "token": token, "tourID": id }).then((response) => {
                        this.deleted = response;
                        this.tours.splice(index, 1);
                    }).catch((error) => {
                        this.errored = error;
                    });
                }
            }
        },
        save: function () {
            this.item.title = this.$refs['item.id'].value;
            this.editingTour = !this.editingTour;
            console.log(this.item.title);
        }
    }
});
```

No `console.log(this.item.title);` está retornando `undefined`. No `ref="item.id"` já tentei deixar `ref="title"` com `this.item.title = this.$refs['item.id'].value;` recebendo `this.item.title = this.$refs['title'].value;` mas não adiantou.

O que estou deixando passar? Poderiam me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

Usa o valor do ID do item a ser editado no `editingTour`, e somente `false` para quando não houver nenhum (ou `-1` para indicar que está sem valor).

No botão para editar atribuis o ID:

```
<button 
    v-if="editingTour !== item.id"
    @click="editingTour = item.id"                
    class="btn border btn-circle tour-list-edit-btn">Editar</button>
```

E no template faz `:disabled="editingTour !== item.id"`. Assim ele só ativa o input quando tiver o item certo.

Comment: Show cara! Desculpe a demora. O `input` do título tá show de bola. Só o botão Salvar e Cancelar ainda tão abrindo em todos. Tentei colocar algumas formas seguindo seu exemplo mas ainda não consegui. Pode me ajudar? Consegui ocultar outros elementos que coloquei no layout seguindo seu exemplo `<span :hidden="editingTour !== item.id">` mas a lógica dos botões ainda não consegui definir

Comment: @madsongr se tens problemas noutros faz outra pergunta a descrever o problema para te ajudarmos